# Unexpected token export when converting from Babel 6 to Babel 7

Tags: reactjs, babeljs, create-react-app

Het all, I'm converting to create-react-app 2.1.1, and it requires Webpack 7.0.0 as a dependency. But when I convert my app from Babel 6 to Babel 7, I'm getting this error:

[image: I'm converting from Babel 6 -> Babel 7, and I'm getting this error:]

The error is coming from inside @babel/runtime in my node_modules, which I'd expect to be ignored.

This is the original code using babel-register `require()` I'm using:

[image][enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/os8Vm.png)

This is the updated code using @babel/register `require()` I'm using:

[image]

This is my package.json:

```

```
{
  "name": "klaw-boilerplate-mernt",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.1.6",
    "@babel/helper-module-transforms": "^7.1.0",
    "@babel/register": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.1.0",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.1.0",
    ...
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    ...
  }
}
```

```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and was able to solve it with this.

```
// server/index.js
require("ignore-styles");
require("url-loader");
require("file-loader");
require("@babel/polyfill");
require("@babel/register");

// your custom stuff
```

In my case I moved the *presets* line to a `.babelrc` file but it shouldn't matter.

```
// .babelrc

{
    "presets": ["@babel/env", "@babel/preset-react"]
}
```

Uninstall `syntax-dynamic-import`, `dynamic-import-node`, `react-loadable/babel` and `react-app`. 
From what I gather, because these are older versions they are not compatible leading to the error. `node_modules` is ignored by default.

Here are the important entries in `package.json`.

```
{
    "dependencies": {
        "@babel/polyfill": "^7.2.5",
        "@babel/preset-env": "^7.2.3",
        "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
        "@babel/register": "^7.0.0",
        "file-loader": "^3.0.1",
        "url-loader": "^1.1.2",
    }
}
```

*Some of these names can also be abbreviated when using them but I like to keep the full names*